# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /pizzas?&_sort=popular&_order=desc from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/ (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, axios, синтаксис

Скачал с https://github.com/Archakov06/react-pizza. Запустил у себя на компьютере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Привожу файл с ошибкой

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export const setLoaded = (payload) => ({
  type: 'SET_LOADED',
  payload,
});

export const fetchPizzas = (sortBy, category) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'SET_LOADED',
    payload: false,
  });

  axios
    .get(
      `/pizzas?${category !== null ? `category=${category}` : ''}&_sort=${sortBy.type}&_order=${
        sortBy.order
      }`,
    )
    .then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch(setPizzas(data));
    });
};

export const setPizzas = (items) => ({
  type: 'SET_PIZZAS',
  payload: items,
});
```

Подскажите как устранить ошибку.

2. Еще выдает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу файл package.json

```js
{
  "name": "react-pizza",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "4.3.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.10.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.6",
    "camelcase": "^5.3.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "24.9.0",
    "jest-watch-typeahead": "0.4.2",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.6.4",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-normalize": "8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "resolve": "1.15.0",
    "semver": "6.3.0",
    "ts-pnp": "1.1.6",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js",
    "server": "node server.js",
    "json-server": "json-server --watch public/db.json --port=3001"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^9.1.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "file-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "^4.0.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^5.1.4",
    "react-dev-utils": "^10.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5",
    "url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

Может помимо npm start надо запустить server.js? Если да, то как это делается?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам нужно запустить сервер (основанный `json-server`), команды для запуска уже существуют, их можно посмотреть в `package.json` (свойство `scripts`). Там есть `server` и его можно запустить: `npm run server`.

Comment: как запустить последовательность скриптов. Пытался выполнить  `npm run server, npm run start`,  но выдало ошибку. После запуска npm run server не знаю как запустить другие скрипты.

Comment: @fullsearch запустите как две отдельные каманды в разных окнах консоли