# Одновременный запуск npm run server и другого скрипта

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

В связи с [Proxy error: Could not proxy request /pizzas?&_sort=popular&_order=desc from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/ (ECONNREFUSED)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1341097/proxy-error-could-not-proxy-request-pizzas-sort-popular-order-desc-from-loc) возник вопрос как запустить 2 скрипта (npm run server)  и другой скрипт (npm run start) в указанной последовательности (сначала server, а потом другой)?

Answer (score 0):

```
nohup npm run server > output.txt &
npm run start
```

nohup документация и описание: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_base/node44.html